# Image loading on tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi guys please correct me, I have a problem loading an image on tkinter, when the program run it shows that the `file is not found`.

```
from tkinter import *


from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window=Tk()

window.geometry("600x500")

path = "new.jpg"

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))


window.mainloop ()
```

Error log

> > In open fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
> >     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'new.jpg'

Comment: Is `new.jpg` in the current working directory?

Comment: aah yes it's on desktop !!!